# Issue with function to generate letter combinations in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that will output all possible combinations of letters, alternating with consonants and vowels.  It should output:

Consonant + Vowel + Consonant + Vowel + Consonant + Vowel --or-- bababa...

I have the first two letters outputting correctly, but I'm stuck on adding more.  My problem is where to put the for loops after what is below.

I'm just cout-ing this on the console now (for testing), but once it's working I'm going to output this into a file for later reference.

```
void createWord(char consonants[], char vowels[])
{
//CLENGTH = 21, and VLENGTH = 5, with consonants[] as a cstring with all
consonants, and vowels[] as a cstring with all vowels.

int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < CLENGTH; i++)
{

    for (j = 0; j<VLENGTH; j++)
    {
        cout << consonants[i] << vowels[j] ;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like an almost surprising number of "generate all the combinations" type of problems, this can be solved by counting.

Start with a couple of strings to convert from numeric to character representation:

```
char const *consonants[] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
char const *vowels[] = "aeiou";
```

The we can just count, and use the right parts of our number as indices into the arrays:

```
// I'll arbitrarily pick 10000 as the number to print out.
for (size_t i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    size_t digit_0 = i % 21;
    i /= 21;
    size_t digit_1 = i % 5;
    i /= 5;
    size_t digit_2 = i % 21;
    i /= 21;
    size_t digit_3 = i % 5;

    std::cout << consonants[digit_0] 
              << vowels[digit_1] 
              << consonants[digit_2] 
              << vowels[digit_3] 
              << "\n";
}
```